# How to convert NSArray of NSNumbers into NSData

Tags: objective-c, ios, titanium, nsdata, titanium-modules

I'm new to Objective C and am modifying an iOS module for the Titanium framework which sends UDP packets. The module currently lets you pass in a text string to send, and it will convert it to bytes and send it via UDP to a destination ip and port. This works great and here is the code:

https://github.com/chrisfjones/titanium_module_udp/blob/master/UDPSocketProxy.m

What I want to do is pass a byte array into the send function instead of a string and have it just send it. Here is the Titanium code:

```
var udp = require('chrisfjones.titanium_module_udp');
var socket = udp.createUDP();
var bytes = [ 100, 15, 132, 53, 14, 246, 0, 0, 0, 0, 196, 209, 1, 1, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 16, 0, 45, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 158, 4, 111, 30, 179, 41 ];
socket.send(bytes, "1.2.3.4", 6100);
```

And here is the new send function so far:

```
- (void) sendBytes: (NSArray*) args {

    NSArray *msg       = (NSArray*)[args objectAtIndex: 0];

    NSString *host      = [TiUtils stringValue:[args objectAtIndex: 1]];

    NSInteger port      = [TiUtils intValue:   [args objectAtIndex: 2]];


NSLog(@"%@ send bytes: %@ to %@:%i", self, msg, host, port);


struct sockaddr_in destinationAddress;

    socklen_t sockaddr_destaddr_len = sizeof(destinationAddress);



    memset(&destinationAddress, 0, sockaddr_destaddr_len);

    destinationAddress.sin_len = (__uint8_t) sockaddr_destaddr_len;

    destinationAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;

    destinationAddress.sin_port = htons(port);

    destinationAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr([host cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]);



    NSData *destinationAddressData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&destinationAddress length:sizeof(destinationAddress)];



    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:msg];



    CFSocketError socket_error = CFSocketSendData(_socket, (CFDataRef) destinationAddressData, (CFDataRef) data, 10);

    if (socket_error) {

        NSLog(@"socket error: %li", socket_error);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"sent bytes: '%@' to %@:%i", msg, host, port);

    }

}
```

You'll notice that it passes in a NSArray. That is because Titanium converts the javascript array that I create into a NSArray of NSNumber objects. I read that this is terribly inefficient but it's built into the Titanium framework so I don't see a way around it, so I'm hoping for an answer on how to make it work with this getting passed in, not a lecture on how inefficient it is.

When I call the new send method, instead of it sending the 50 or so bytes that I pass in, I can see in wireshark that it is actually passing over 1000 bytes. I'm assuming the issue is with the conversion on this line:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:msg];
```

Can someone please help on how to just send the byte array that I pass in? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you don't want to use the archiver in this case, since you're just trying to turn a set of bytes into a block of `NSData`.   Depending on whether you are passing in an array of `NSNumber` or an array of `NSString`, you'll basically need to loop over the contents of the array and append the data to an `NSMutableData`.

Assuming it's an array of `NSNumber`, then something like this should work:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity: [msg count]];
for( NSNumber *number in msg) {
    char byte = [number charValue];
    [data appendBytes: &byte length: 1];
}
// .... code that uses data ...
[data release];
```

If the numbers are numeric values in string form, you'll probably want to use the `-(int)intValue` method of `NSString` to pull out the data and then add that to the data, basically changing the above to:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity: [msg count]];
for( NSString *string in msg) {
    char byte = (char)[string intValue];
    [data appendBytes: &byte length: 1];
}
// .... code that uses data ...
[data release];
```

And, if you're trying to stuff the characters from the strings, then you'll need to grab the character using `[string characterAtIndex: 0]` and compensate for the fact that you will be receiving a `unichar` instead of a `char`.

Comment: Works great, thanks! One little change, the "args" in the first and second lines should be "msg".

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSData *)byteArray2Data:(NSArray *)array {
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber* number, NSUInteger index, BOOL* stop) {
        uint8_t tmp = number.unsignedCharValue;
        [data appendBytes:(void *)(&tmp)length:1];
    }];

    return data;
}

- (NSArray *)byteData2Array:(NSData *)data {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [data enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:^(const void *bytes, NSRange byteRange, BOOL *stop) {
        unsigned char *dataBytes = (unsigned char*)bytes;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < byteRange.length; i++) {
            [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(dataBytes[i]) & 0xff]];
        }
    }];

    return array;
}
```